# Load product list under category navigation magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am creating Magento  website.I am using `Magento 1.9.2` and `luxury theme 1.2.x`

In here I have created left category navigation bar.I want to load all product list under their appropriate category.

I want to know how to achieve it, Or it is not possible to do?Or is there any application available for magento?

And where can I find that category navigation .phtml file?

FYI I am attaching my screenshot.In Product category section i want to load products. Example load all product under Main Door Lock, Jemmy Proof Door Lock etc

[image]

**EDIT:**

I found this File for left navigation but when I am making changes in it, Don't do anything.

app\design\frontend\mgstheme\luxury\template\mgs\mpanel\template\category-navigation.phtml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: assign products to selective categories under admin->catalog->manage categories

Comment: @faizanbeg I have assigned products to categories.... now I need way to display it (load) under that category in the frontend.

Comment: you dont need to load product under categories it show products by default . Do you want to show in other page?

Comment: Actually i want to show products in the drop down